# Replace the content of _top window with content of iframe without reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to replace the content of the browser window (_top frame) with the document loaded in an iframe, without issuing a new GET to load that document?

Something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").click(function() {
    // should present in the browser window the content of the iframe WITHOUT reload
    // even preserve javascript/head code
    $(document).html($("#frameDestination").html());
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="link" href="#">full window</a>
<iframe id="frameDestination" src="http://www.some-random-site.com" width="900px" height="500px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me make sure we understand the problem correctly: You have a page with an anchor tag and an iframe. On click on the anchor tag, you want the entire page to become what was in the iframe (without making any HTTP requests)?

Comment: I can't think of any way this would be possible. It might be possible to re-position the iframe to cover the entire browser window, but it would still be nested within the original page.

Comment: @jbabey Exactly!  I want to simulate as if the page is just loaded by typing in the URL in the browser's address bar. I don't want a new roundtrip to the server asking for the same HTML document since it is already loaded in the iframe.

Comment: Well if it had proper caching headers set, it would not hit the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use contents() when working with an iframe in jQuery.

```
$("#YourIframe").contents().find("html").html();
```

This is **only** going to work if the iframe is in the **same domain** as the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested cross domain, but on the same domain I have this script working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").click(function() {
    var iframeBody = document.getElementById("frameDestination").contentDocument,
    head = iframeBody['head'].innerHTML, 
    body = iframeBody['body'].innerHTML;
    $('body').html( body );
    $('head').html( head );
  });
});
```

In the latest Firefox, I'm even able to set a variable in a script tag in the frame, and see that value in _top after clicking the link.

Comment: Thanks @Gitninja! It works like a charm for the same domain, but just tested it with a different domain and does not work (FF and Chrome).

Comment: I've read that if the iframe src is set by javascript, then the cross domain restriction doesn't apply, but I haven't tested yet. Are you able to dynamically generate the iframe tag using javascript in your situtation?

Comment: @Gitnija: Does not work with: `var ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.somesite.com");
ifrm.setAttribute("id", "frameDestination");
ifrm.style.width = 1200+"px"; 
ifrm.style.height = 500+"px"; 
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);`

Comment: There's two problems I've run into trying this: 1) some domains won't let you load in iframe (ex:google.com), 2) the browser denies permission to access these parts. I know there are some security settings that users can disable in firefox that *may* make this possible, but only if the user follows instructions. I'm going to agree with @epascarello that it can't be done across domains.